# nt Redirect Error when running Scraping Script in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm working with a Python Script to scrape the Website of a used car platform. Aim is to generate a JSON File with all the different Parameters of all the listings.

I took the code from a german guy that made it, made some changes to reflect how the updated site works, but I can't quite get it to work.

When running the Script I get the following Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):nt Redirect                                                  
  File "main.py", line 53, in <module>
    for link in soup.find_all("a"):
NameError: name 'soup' is not defined
```

I'm not really understanding what it's trying to tell me here?

I'm guessing the website tries to redirect and it doesn't really work but I don't understand why, and don't have any idea how to fix it.

I'd appreciate your help or any pointers on how to get it to work.

The full code here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer #HTML parsing
import urllib.request #aufrufen von URLs
from time import sleep #damit legen wir den Scraper schlafen
import json #lesen und schreiben von JSON-Dateien
from datetime import datetime #um den Daten Timestamps zu geben
import re #regular expressions
import os #Dateipfade erstellen und lesen
import pandas as pd #Datenanalyse und -manipulation
folders = ["data/visited/","data/autos/"]
for folder in folders:
    if not os.path.isdir(folder):
        os.mkdir(folder)
        print(path, "erstellt.")
    else:
        print(folder,"existiert bereits")
path_to_visited_urls = "data/visited/visited_urls.json"
if not os.path.isfile(path_to_visited_urls):
    with open(path_to_visited_urls,"w") as file:
        json.dump([],file)
countries = {"Deutschland": "D",
             "Oesterreich": "A",
             "Belgien" : "B",
             "Spanien": "E",
             "Frankreich": "F",
             "Italien": "I",
             "Luxemburg": "L",
             "Niederlande": "NL"}
#countries = {"Deutschland": "D"}
car_counter=1
cycle_counter=0
while True:
    with open(path_to_visited_urls) as file:
        visited_urls = json.load(file)
    
    if len(visited_urls) > 100000:
        visited_urls = []
    
    multiple_cars_dict = {}
    
    cycle_counter+=1
    for country in countries:
        
        car_URLs = []
        
        for page in range(1,21):
            try:
                url = 'https://www.autoscout24.de/lst/?sort=age&desc=1&ustate=N%2CU&size=20&page='+str(page)+ '&cy=' + countries[country] +'&atype=C&'
                only_a_tags = SoupStrainer("a")
                soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(),'lxml', parse_only=only_a_tags)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Übersicht: " + str(e) +" "*50, end="\r")
                pass
            for link in soup.find_all("a"):
                if r"/angebote/" in str(link.get("href")):
                    car_URLs.append(link.get("href"))
            car_URLs_unique = [car for car in list(set(car_URLs)) if car not in visited_urls]
            
            print(f'Lauf {cycle_counter} | {country} | Seite {page} | {len(car_URLs_unique)} neue URLs', end="\r")
        print("")
        if len(car_URLs_unique)>0:
            for URL in car_URLs_unique:
                print(f'Lauf {cycle_counter} | {country} | Auto {car_counter}'+' '*50, end="\r")
                try:
                    car_counter+=1
                    car_dict = {}
                    car_dict["country"] = country
                    car_dict["date"] = str(datetime.now())                    
                    car = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.autoscout24.de'+URL).read(),'lxml')
                    
                    for key, value in zip(car.find_all("dt"),car.find_all("dd")):
                        car_dict[key.text.replace("\n","")] = value.text.replace("\n","")
                    car_dict["haendler"] = car.find("div",attrs={"class":"cldt-vendor-contact-box",
                                                                 "data-vendor-type":"dealer"}) != None
                    car_dict["privat"] = car.find("div",attrs={"class":"cldt-vendor-contact-box",
                                                               "data-vendor-type":"privateseller"}) != None
                    car_dict["ort"] = car.find("a",attrs={"class":"css-1jedbw8"}).text,
                
                    
                    car_dict["price"] = "".join(re.findall(r"[0-9]+",car.find("span",attrs={"class":"css-113e8xo"}).text))
                    
                    ausstattung = []
                    for i in car.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"cldt-equipment-block sc-grid-col-3 sc-grid-col-m-4 sc-grid-col-s-12 sc-pull-left"}):
                        for span in i.find_all("span"):
                            ausstattung.append(i.text)
                    ausstattung2 = []
                    for element in list(set(ausstattung)):
                        austattung_liste = element.split("\n")
                        ausstattung2.extend(austattung_liste)
                    car_dict["ausstattung_liste"] = sorted(list(set(ausstattung2)))
                    multiple_cars_dict[URL] = car_dict
                    visited_urls.append(URL)
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Detailseite: " + str(e) + " "*50)
                    pass
            print("")
        
        else:
            print("\U0001F634")
            sleep(60)
    
    if len(multiple_cars_dict)>0:
        df = pd.DataFrame(multiple_cars_dict).T
        df.to_csv("data/autos/"+re.sub("[.,:,-, ]","_",str(datetime.now()))+".csv",sep=";",index_label="url")
    else:
        print("Keine Daten")
    with open("data/visited/visited_urls.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(visited_urls, file)
```

I tried to fix it by editing the line in question (53), but I don't even really understand what that specific line does so - I got nothing.

Comment: Did you write the code above, or did you copy-paste it from somewhere?

Comment: copied it as mentioned. Here's the link: https://statisquo.de/2020/01/16/autoscout24-mining-webscraping-mit-python/

Comment: Without looking too hard into it, I doubt autoscout/mobile.de are not protected too the teeth against webscraping. You should probably look into a Selenium or Playwright based solution.Oh - and that code is 3 years old. Landscape tends to change in webscraping matters.